# Sort range by numbers (which contains numbers and strings)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort a list by using `Range.Sort`. But I wish I could sort by just a part of the cell value. Just the numbers from left to right, to be more precise.
Is there a way of filter the value in middle of sort command?
See attached examples of values that may be contained in the `Key1` parameter. The strings doesn't have a standard. Sometimes may contain symbols, such as ± or + or -, sometimes just numbers. [Entry examples for sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YERD.png).

Below is the code I have so far.

```
    Sub SortTag()

    '______________________________
    'verificar se há células filtradas antes de iniciar a reorganização
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            Dim LimpaFiltro As Long
            LimpaFiltro = MsgBox(Title:="Planilha Filtrada!", _
                                 prompt:="A planilha possui células filtradas" & _
                                 vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Deseja continuar?", _
                                 Buttons:=vbYesNo)
            If LimpaFiltro = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            If LimpaFiltro = vbYes Then
                    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
            End If
    End If
    '______________________________

    'cria o range que será reornizado
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range '.Offset(1). _
                    Resize(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1)
    rng.Sort key1:=rng.Columns(1), _
                    order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Header:=xlYes

    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:

    End Sub
```

Comment: May be you can split the cell values  and put them (numbers only) in a new column and then sort the new column.

Comment: You can use isnumeric function and put it in a loop: for i = 1 to len(.cell(1,1).value) to split numbers from the string.